# How to hide file path while rendering

Tags: solidify-modifier

How to hide file path while rendering.
I've never had this problem before and my experience with the software is medium to poor.
I did not find the solution to this problem.
Can someone help me with that
thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZyaN.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the checkbox "Burn into image" under Output properties -> Metadata.

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir..with all due respect and appreciation for your time.

Comment: if it helped you, please check the checkmark left to my answer. thank you.